# Prevent didSelectRowAtIndexPath being called for STTweetLabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, custom-component, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm using [this](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel) custom component for hashtag detection in my app. I have added STTweetLabel's as subviews to my custom table view cells. However, clicking on any hashtag invokes the [STTweetLabel](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/STTweetLabel) handler block AND also calls the tableview's `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate which results in a push to another controller. How do I disable this from happening? i.e. prevent the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` behaviour on the STTweetLabels?

```
Code:
[hashtagLabel setDetectionBlock:^(STTweetHotWord hotWord, NSString *string, NSString *protocol, NSRange range) {
            // call delegate to respond to hashtag selection
        }];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to delete

`[super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];`
`[super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];`
`[super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];`

in STTweetLabel.m

I use [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/mattt/TTTAttributedLabel) now, you can also try it.

Comment: Perfect! That worked. I dont exactly know how since I'm a novice but I'm guessing the STTweetLabel component forwards the touches up the view chain where it is caught by the contained UITableView?

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is cell highlight then use this.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Or use this for prevent invoke didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

```
tableView:willSelectRowAtIndexPath:
```

I hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You can either prevent the cell from being selected at all in the interface builder or in code using the `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` selection style.

or in your `-(NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method return nil for the indexPath of the cells you don't want to get selected

Comment: I do need the didSelectRowAtIndexPath invocation for the rest of the cell. I only need to prevent from happening when interacting with the hashtag labels.

Comment: Do you do some action in  didSelectRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: @iMobile Yes I do, I push to another view.

Comment: If your label covers whole cell?

Comment: maybe you could use a disclosure indicator accessory view in your cell that you use to push to your other view and remove that code from didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @Argent the app design doesn't allow for an accessory view :( IF nothing works, I'd leave that as the last option

Comment: @iMobile no it doesn't cover the whole cell

Answer (score 0):

Actually didSelectRowAtIndexPath method always get called first and this solution may work if your label will not cover whole your cell.

If you are doing some task in didSelectRowAtIndexPath then do this steps

1> `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;`

2> make custom cell put button back side of label .On button put uilabel  then you can add action  on that button and do some task when button tapped and as well you can detect label tap seperately

Answer (score 0):

the dirty way:

put your `STTweetLabel` inside an `UIButton` without `target` and `action`